# Проблемы при подключении библиотеки FloatingButton android

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Нашел прикольную плавающую кнопку, для замены стандартной кнопки, которая создается при добавлении `Navigation_Drawer`. Вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4Mu6g_M71s) которое я использую для подключения кнопки. Я пытаюсь вставить эту кнопку вместо моей стандартной кнопки в файле `app_bar_...`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--<io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
            android:id="@+id/speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_menu"
            app:miniFabBackgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>-->


       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

вроде замещение должно проходить нормально, но почему-то слетает приложение с такой ошибкой:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.MessageCenter.MessageCenter}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
```

если я правильно понял, проблемы с каким-то классом этой библиотеки. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Весь лог ошибки покажите - понятно что не создаётся `FabSpeedDial`, но по какой причине...

Comment: @woesss, а может быть такое что эта ошибка из-за того, что иконки не привязаны в менюшке для этой кнопки, я просто все по новой делать начал))